# What mechanism is this?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I was solving problems in Organic Chemistry related to Substitution and Elimination. This was a question asked in JEE 2019

[image: The question]

This was the solution for above.

[image]

At last of solution, It has been mentioned that after rearrangement it undergoes"ArS<sub>E</sub>2 Pathway".

What is meant by ArS<sub>E</sub>2 pathway/mechanism?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophilic_aromatic_substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a standard [Friedel-Crafts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedel%E2%80%93Crafts_reaction) reaction, although it is intramolecular rather than intermolecular. The cation undergoes [electrophilic substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophilic_substitution) to give the product.

The choice of terminology used by the authors is strange: a search for "ArS<sub>E</sub>2" returns very few links, such as [this one](https://www.quora.com/Explain-how-the-absence-of-the-kinetic-isotropic-effect-in-ArSE2-reaction-establishes-that-it-is-not-a-single-step-reaction). **There seems to be no commonly known reaction mechanism with this name**, and the author was most likely referring to standard electrophilic substitution.

Comment: Electrophilic aromatic substitution is denoted as $\ce{S_{E}Ar}$.